# How can I set a property inside route deactivate to use inside controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a ember route as follows which uses deactivate function to set some properties when route deactivation.

```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
       deactivate: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('scrollSelector',mainContainer);
      // need to set property here and use it inside controller
    }
    });
```

How can I set property inside `deactivate` method to be used inside `controller` level. ?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you need to set controller property inside deactivate hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `this.controller`

```
this.controller.set('propertyname','value');
```

You can even try  `this.controllerFor(this.routeName);` to get controller object